# What was the first movie to introduce J Cut in opening credits?

Tags: first-appearance

In **[Money Monster (2016)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2241351/)**, audio/dialogue is audible before the picture comes in.

What was the first movie to introduce a J-Cut in the opening credits?

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the definition of "J-Cut", [here's the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_cut).